# Views, Taxonomy, Tokens and URL

Tags: 7, views, uri, tokens

I am building a website for multiple summer resorts. I am now concentrating on the restaurants section.

I have a content type - Restaurant.

It has multiple fields but I will just put down the ones that are connected to this question;

```
field_resort: Term Ref.
field_restaurant_category: Term Ref.
```

And then the url pattern;

```
[node:field-resort]/restaurant-guide/[node:title]
```

---

I need a block in the restaurant parent page [node:field-resort]/**restaurants** that then displays a grid with each individual taxonomy term [field_restaurant_category].

What the problem is is that I want to have a page that once you click on one of those categories, takes you to a page that displays teaser views of all the restaurants for that specific food categorie from only that resort while appending the url to keep the resort as the parent.

```
resort-1/restaurant-guide/[field_restaurant_category]
resort-2/restaurant-guide/[field_restaurant_category]
resort-3/restaurant-guide/[field_restaurant_category]
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! So far, you stated facts, but you didn't ask any explicit question.

Answer (score 0):

In Views the pattern for the path cannot have a contextual filter as the first part of the path.

[Contextual filters and paths](https://www.drupal.org/node/1578576)

> The normal way a view gets values for contextual filters is by the
>   view path. The easiest way of doing this is to append filter values to
>   the path, separated by slashes. It is also possible to have contextual
>   filter values within a path. This is done by using a percent sign
>   where the view expects a contextual filter value in the path of the
>   view (for example user/%/comments).

So your pattern needs to change to something like this:

```
resorts/%/restaurant-guide/%
```

as in resorts/[resort]/restaurant-guide/[restaurant-category]

Then two contextual filters:

```
**content resort (field resort)**
Taxonomy term ID from URL
Validator: Taxonomy Term
Vocabulary: resort
Filter value type: Term name converted to Term ID


**content restaurant category (field restaurant category)**
Same as above but with Vocabulary: restaurant category
```

Then keep in mind that you might need to deal with spaces in your taxonomy terms

Comment: @ArronMurray, please mark the answer as correct if it worked

Answer (score 0):

I was a bit of a novice when it came to contextual filters.

Taxonomy term ID from URL
Validator: Taxonomy Term
Vocabulary: resort
Filter value type: Term name converted to Term ID

**content restaurant category (field restaurant category)**
Same as above but with Vocabulary: restaurant category

This worked